# How can I make qbittorrent's unity icon work?

Tags: qbittorrent

I just installed qbittorrent, and the unity icon automatically appeared in the launcher. So far so good. When I click on it, qbittorrent launches. However, there is no indication that the program is running, i.e. no little triangle to the left or right of the icon. When qbittorrent is behind a few windows, clicking on the unity launcher icon makes the launcher icon flash, but doesn't focus qBittorrent. In other words, it doesn't look like the unity icon is working. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has an opened bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/qbittorrent/+bug/773901)

You may want to use transmission-gtk (gtk bittorrent client) + torrentsearch.

Install transmission-gtk with:

```
sudo apt-get install transmission-gtk
```

And download torrentsearch [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/torrent-search/files/torrent-search/0.9.2.3/torrent-search_0.9.2.3_all.deb/download)

Comment: The link shows that a fixed has been released.

Comment: I'm afraid the fix is only from 12.04 on, as the version coming with 11.04 and 11.10 was last updated (2011) before the fix was released (March 2012).

Answer (score 0):

I just installed it from USC, and it works perfect.  It shows the little triangle on the icon that indicates that it is working.  Make sure that you are up-to-date with updates.

[image]